# Fix "Cannot update component from inside function body of different component" warning in React Native app using Context

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, apollo

I have a simple RN app that pretty much only has login so far. It uses Apollo GraphQL to call the backend and stores the user token and name in a React Context object. The context object has the user and a setUser function (and is instantiated in App.js). The login screen calls setUser from the UserContext object on a successful login.

This has been working fine but today I updated to React 16.3 and started getting the warning:

> Cannot update a component from inside the function body of a different component

And lists the line where I am calling the setUser function if we received a succesful response.

The App.js uses useState to track the user and setUser function and puts that in a object to pass into the UserContext.Provider:

```
export default function App(props) {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null)
  const contextVal = { user: user, setUser: setUser }

    return (
      <ApolloProvider client={client}>
        <UserContext.Provider value={contextVal}>
          <View style={styles.container}>
            {Platform.OS === 'ios' && <StatusBar barStyle="default" />}
            <AppNavigator />
          </View>
        </UserContext.Provider>
      </ApolloProvider>
    );
}
```

And the LoginScreen retrieves user and setUser from the UserContext and when it gets `data` from the sigin mutation, tries to pass a simple user object to setUser:

```
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('')
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('')
  const [signin, { data, error, loading }] = useMutation(SIGNIN_MUTATION)
  const { user, setUser } = useContext(UserContext)

  useEffect(() => {
    if (user) {
      props.navigation.navigate('Main')
    }
  }, [user])

  if (loading) return (
    <View style={styles.main}>
      <Text style={styles.text}>Logging you in!</Text>
      <ActivityIndicator size='large' />
    </View>
  )

  if (data) { // ERROR IS HERE
    setUser({
      token: data.signin.token,
      name: data.signin.user.name,
    })
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.main}>
      <Text style={styles.welcome}>Welcome to Bravauto!</Text>
      <Text style={styles.error}>{error ? errorMessage(error) : ''}</Text>
      <Text>Please login to continue:</Text>
      <TextInput style={styles.input} onChangeText={(text) => setEmail(text)} placeholder="email" />
      <TextInput style={styles.input} onChangeText={(text) => setPassword(text)} placeholder="password" secureTextEntry={true} />
      <Button title="Login!" onPress={() => signin({ variables: { email: email, password: password } })} />
      <Button title="No Account? Register Here" onPress={() => props.navigation.navigate('Registration')} />
    </View>
  )
```

I remember that to get this working I had to wrap the "already have a user" case (where it calls props.navigate) in a useEffect call, and I found other posts suggesting that wrapping this code in useEffect will fix the warning. However if I wrap this code in a useEffect hook like this:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (data) {
      setUser({
        token: data.signin.token,
        name: data.signin.user.name,
      })
    }
  })
```

I get an error instead of a warning:

> Rendered fewer hooks than expected. This may be caused by an accidental early return statement.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Where is the data variable coming from?

Comment: That's from the data returned from the GraphQL call. In this case, the user name and token.

Answer (score 1):

You will want to include the data field in the list of ones the useEffect is using:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (data) {
      setUser({
        token: data.signin.token,
        name: data.signin.user.name,
      })
    }
  }, [data])
```

Comment: Ah, yeah, forgot to mention that that's what I tried immediately, following the same pattern as the "if(user)" `useEffect` call above it. I get the same "rendered fewer hooks" error. 

I feel like this has to be an issue with the fact that `setUser` is from a `useState` call in App.js but I don't know how else to set the context state. (On the other hand, I'm pondering just using the Apollo cache for my global state and bagging Context altogether.)

Answer (score 1):

Oops, forgot to post that I eventually found the answer to this. The solution was to use the callbacks provided by Apollo:

```
  const [signin, { loading }] = useMutation(SIGNIN_MUTATION, {
    onCompleted: (data) => {
      setAuth(data.signin.token);
    },
    onError: (errorMsg) => {
      setError(errorMessage(errorMsg));
    }, 
    errorPolicy: "none"
  });
```

After changing to this approach everything works fine.